# cannot read property of undefined (trying to access property before initialization)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple image slider.
For that I need to access a property of an element ( const size = carouselImg[0].clientWidth;) that is part of a react component.
However, I'm receiving the " cannot read property of undefined" error which is probably because the whole component hasn't been started/initialized yet hence it's null and we cant get the property.
I'm totally new to react js but I'm guessing I need to store those properties somehow in a state or so.
Does anyone know how to do that?
Much appreciated.
Regards.

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of your code, include the code directly in your question with proper formatting.

Comment: Accessing a DOM element rendered by React is usually done via refs. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Yousaf yeah thats the better way. Im totally new to all of this but ill do it next time.

Comment: @FelixKling ok thanks I'll check that out.

Comment: Are you certain that everything is loaded before you do the querySelectorAll which sets up carouselImg (e.g. is there something like a windows.onload somewhere?). Can you look at entries in dev tools to make sure there are some img elements with the class you expect?

Comment: yeah thats the point.
i think the problem is that im trying to access it before the necessary component is loaded.
So im trying to figure out a way to store the array of images in a way so that i can access it anytime.
So I guess i need to work with state somehow.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, the "size" variable needs to be initialised before the component is initialized.

You can change this line

```
const size = carouselImg[0].clientWidth;
```

to

```
const defaultSize = 0 // whatever you want
const size = carouselImg ? carouselImg[0].clientWidth : defaultSize;
```

This way, if carouselImg hasnt been defined the size will be set to a default.
Or you can set the size after the react initialized hook has been triggered.

Comment: I think its not the size variable but kinda the whole app.
So in the picture you can see that inside the home component I've got a div with some images.
My js code is supposed to create an array out of those images, get the size of one of them cause thats the amount of px it needs to slide to next img.
I followed a youtube tutorial where its exactly the same way however the html code is inside a html file and the js code inside of a seperate file that he references in his scirpt tag
So i want to do the same but put that stuff into my Home.js

Comment: Im thinking wether I should save it somehow in the state.
I kinda want the accessability no matter wether the app is running or not.
So kinda in a static "offline" way so to speak